# IndexedDB in PhoneGap + Android

Tags: android, cordova, indexeddb

I am currently working in a PhoneGap/Cordova app and I'm trying to use IndexedDB to store data. From what I read, Android support for it is rather scarce and so what works in my PC doesn't seem to work in my tablet (Android 4.0.4) nor my phone (4.2.1).

I have been trying to use the [IndexedDB Polyfill](http://nparashuram.com/IndexedDBShim/) as described in [Parashuram's blog](http://blog.nparashuram.com/2012/10/indexeddb-example-on-cordova-phonegap_12.html); however, it doesn't seem to work for my app. What's more, when I run Parashuram's example app in my devices, it doesn't seem to work and the unit tests fail.

Does anyone have any experience with IndexedDB and PhoneGap + Android? What have you used to make your app work?

Incidentally, IndexedDB seems to be implemented in both devices, since this works for both and I can create and open databases:

```
window.indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB
    || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;
```

However, the onupdateneeded event does not seem to be fired, even though I'm using the [jQuery IndexedDB plugin](http://nparashuram.com/jquery-indexeddb/), which is supposed to work around different implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experience with the shim in my project and it works for me on android. What version of Cordova do you use? It doesn't work on Android when using Cordova 3.2 or lower due to this bug: https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/commit/6e4ef508e8f9f2d396515bd1d7465481d2f1285c

Are you using the latest shim version? Because the older ones didn't successfully overwrite the native indexedDB object.

I'm also the co-maintainer of the project so if you have any questions feel free to ask.

Comment: Hi. Sorry I took so long! I'm getting

`Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM IDBDatabase Exception 3`

every time I run the code in my tablet or my phone using the jQuery IndexedDB plugin. Now, when I stop using jQuery and use the raw interface, I keep getting the same error in one device, while the other screams

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'READ_ONLY' of function IDBTransaction() { [native code] } at file:///android_asset/www/app/libs/IndexedDBShim.min.js:2`

Comment: I believe the "Cannot assign" issue is gone in the latest version. Also, there are some fixes for Android, because they implement an old spec on 4.3 and below. Can you try the latest version found here: https://github.com/axemclion/IndexedDBShim/blob/master/dist/IndexedDBShim.js ?

Comment: Works flawlessly now! Thank you very much. :D Now, may I suggest that the version in http://nparashuram.com/IndexedDBShim/ is updated? I used it believing that it was the latest one, hence my previous comments. Again, thank you - and have my apologies for making you work unnecessarily! ;)

Comment: No problem and you are right, we should update that one! Glad to read that the problem is solved! :)

Answer (score 0):

IndexedDB works great in PhoneGap on Android 4.4+ devices. I've used it, it's identical to using IndexedDB in Chrome.

Prior to 4.4, Android's WebView [did not support IndexedDB](http://caniuse.com/indexeddb). There are workarounds, like the shim you linked to, but that path tends to not be a lot of fun. If you can get away with targeting only 4.4+, that will make your life much happier.

Comment: That would definitely make my life much simpler - but unless I can persuade management to provide developers and customers with brand-new devices, I think it's not going to be an option! :(